# How can I do this Spatial Query in Sql 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, spatial

i'm trying to do a spatial query in sql 2008 -> for a given list of POI's (point of interest, long/lat `GEOGRAPHY` data), which postcodes do they exist in (multipolygon `GEOGRAPHY` data).

So this is the query i tried, but it's syntactically incorrect:-

```
SELECT PostCodeId, ShapeFile
FROM Postcodes a
WHERE a.ShapeFile.STIntersects(
    SELECT PointOfInterest
    FROM PointOfInterests
    WHERE PointOfInterestId IN (SELECT Item from dbo.fnSplit(@PoiIdList, ','))
```

So this means i pass in a [csv list of POI Id's and split them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause). That's not a problem .. it's my subquery in the `STIntersects`. That's invalid.

So .. any suggestions folks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT a.PostCodeId, a.ShapeFile
FROM (SELECT Item from dbo.fnSplit(@PoiIdList, ',')) AS POI_IDs
INNER JOIN PointOfInterests
    ON PointOfInterests.PointOfInterestId = POI_IDs.Item
INNER JOIN Postcodes a
    ON a.ShapeFile.STIntersects(PointOfInterests.PointOfInterest) = 1
```

Comment: thanks heaps :) i didn't know u could join the two tables in an STIntersects!

Comment: My only question would really be performance and what's the BEST way to do it.  And right now, that's beyond my understanding (Spatial SQL is all new to me)