# SQL Server check if where clause is true for any row

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2014, spatial-query

I'm going to select those provinces which intersects any railroad. So I do it like this (Using SQL Spatial):

```
SELECT * FROM ProvinceTable
WHERE (
       SELECT count(*)
       FROM RailroadTable
       WHERE ProvinceTable.Shape.STIntersects(RailroadTable.Shape) > 1 
      ) > 0
```

But it is not efficient because it has to check the intersection between every single railroad geometry and province geometry in order to calculate the `count`. However it is better to stop the where clause as soon as every first intersection detected and there is no need to check others. Here is what I mean:

```
SELECT * FROM ProvinceTable
WHERE (
       --return true if this is true for any row in the RailroadTable:
       -- "ProvinceTable.Shape.STIntersects(RailroadTable.Shape) > 1" 
      )
```

So is there a better way to rewrite this query for such a goal?

**EDIT**
Surprisingly This query takes the same time and *returns no row*:

```
SELECT * FROM ProvinceTable
WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM RailroadTable
       WHERE ProvinceTable.Shape.STIntersects(RailroadTable.Shape) > 1 
      )
```

Comment: Can those shape constructs be used in an inner join? Like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/498760/578411)

Comment: I don't think this idea improves the performance because intersection must be check for every single rows using inner join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `exists`:

```
SELECT pt.*
FROM ProvinceTable pt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM RailroadTable rt
              WHERE pt.Shape.STIntersects(rt.Shape) = 1 
             );
```

Comment: I checked this method before and surprisingly it does not returns any row! Moreover it takes as much as `count(*)` method takes time to run!

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad the check would need to be `=1`. This still can end up testing the condition against them Cartesian product though. Do you have any spatial indexes?

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right. No there is no spatial index available. I prefer ed to concentrate on query optimization